# Retrieve information of winning unit in a self organizing map plot

Tags: r, plot, cluster-analysis, self-organizing-maps

I would like to figure out which is the winning unit of a node in the kohonen plot

```
library(kohonen)
set.seed(0)
data("wines")
wines <- scale(wines)
som_grid <- somgrid(8, 6, "hexagonal")
som_model <- som(wines, som_grid)   
plot(som_model)
```

The plot will look like this:

[image: som plot]

And you may know in which cluster the observation will lie with

```
head(data.frame(cbind(wines,unit= som_model$unit.classif)))

  alcohol malic.acid  ash ash.alkalinity magnesium tot..phenols flavonoids non.flav..phenols proanth col..int. col..hue
  1   13.20       1.78 2.14           11.2       100         2.65       2.76              0.26    1.28      4.38     1.05
  2   13.16       2.36 2.67           18.6       101         2.80       3.24              0.30    2.81      5.68     1.03
  3   14.37       1.95 2.50           16.8       113         3.85       3.49              0.24    2.18      7.80     0.86
  4   13.24       2.59 2.87           21.0       118         2.80       2.69              0.39    1.82      4.32     1.04
  5   14.20       1.76 2.45           15.2       112         3.27       3.39              0.34    1.97      6.75     1.05
  6   14.39       1.87 2.45           14.6        96         2.50       2.52              0.30    1.98      5.25     1.02
    OD.ratio proline     unit
  1     3.40    1050      24
  2     3.17    1185      46
  3     3.45    1480      48
  4     2.93     735       4
  5     2.85    1450      48
  6     3.58    1290      47
```

But I would like to retrieve this unit information in the plot, like putting a text in the nodes with this unit number in the same way that identify function does, but automatically. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand which labels you want to put inside the plot. `unique(sm$unit.classif)` yields n=1,2,...,48 clusters. So do you want to put a "cluster 1" into / above the first circle in the row 1 columns 1, then "cluster 2" into circle at row1, col2 .... all the way down to row6, col8 ?

Comment: The plot was wrong. I've fixed.